# Not showing proper type in swagger generated document for JsonDocument type

Tags: .net-core, swagger-ui, swagger-codegen, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

For JsonDocument Type the expected type should be object in swagger documentation but it is creating string as a default.

I have a model in C# which have a type JsonDocument

```
public record SummerCropCommand
{
    public JsonDocument? SummerLivestockType { get; set; }
    public JsonDocument? SummerGrazingStartDate { get; set; }
    public JsonDocument? SummerCountOfHead { get; set; }
    public JsonDocument? SummerDaysGrazing { get; set; }
}
```

Expected behavior
**json**

```
SummerCropCommand:
     type: object
     properties:
       summerLivestockType:
         nullable: true
         type: object
       summerGrazingStartDate:
         nullable: true
         type: object
       summerCountOfHead:
         nullable: true
         type: object
       summerDaysGrazing:
         nullable: true
         type: object
     additionalProperties: false
```

**ui**

```
"summerCrop": { "summerLivestockType": {}, "summerGrazingStartDate": {}, "summerCountOfHead": {}, "summerDaysGrazing": {} }
```

Current behavior
**json**

```
"SummerCropCommand": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "summerLivestockType": {
            "nullable": true
          },
          "summerGrazingStartDate": {
            "nullable": true
          },
          "summerCountOfHead": {
            "nullable": true
          },
          "summerDaysGrazing": {
            "nullable": true
          }
        }
```

**UI**

```
"summerCrop": { "summerLivestockType": "string", "summerGrazingStartDate": "string", "summerCountOfHead": "string", "summerDaysGrazing": "string" }
```

Comment: I find stack**overflow** questions to work best when there is an explicit answerable question near the bottom.